# Where can I ask a question about aircraft tracking algorithms?

Tags: discussion, tags, site-recommendation

Where should I ask questions about tracking algorithms that is used for example in radars?

I see that there are tags for both [Radar](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radar) and [tracking](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tracking) on Electrical Engineering SE. But I did not find tags for **tracking algorithms**.

Comment: Did you check to see if the Aviation site would accept it?

Comment: no i did not, i do not think it is the right place to ask such questions

Comment: Maybe [cs.se]?.

Comment: I do not think it is related to the computer science, what happen if i posted a question not related to the site it is posted in?

Comment: Definitely not for Electrical Engineering if you are asking about algorithms. EE is for designing electronics, not software. If you want to discuss algorithms, you might be able to go to mathematics.SE or software-recommendations.SE if you want to find existing software.